# Read table with solo comma in column

Tags: r, read.csv

I have csv file that looks like this:

```
BROJ_OBRASCA;POSLOVNICA;SIF_OPER;MATBROJ;OIB;MBS;RNO;NAZIV;POSTA;MJESTO;ADRESA;NKD2002;NKD2007;ZUPANIJA;OPCINA;DATUMUNOSA;VRSTA_IZV;E_MAIL;OZN_LIKV_STEC;KONTAKT_OSOBA;TEL;FAX;ZAKON_PREDSTAV;SIF_OBL_ORG;ULAZI;ZAD_PROM;DAT_STANJA_OD;DAT_STANJA;VEL;VLAST;OZN_KONS;REVIDIRAN;SVRHA;KAP_DOM;KAP_INO;ZAPOSL_STPR;ZAPOSL_SATIPR;ZAPOSL_STTK;ZAPOSL_SATITK;SERVIS_MB;SERVIS_NAZIV;SERVIS_EMAIL;MJ_POSL_PR;MJ_POSL_TK;KAKO;AUTONOM;DRZ_MATICE;MB_MATICE;DOBGUB;OIB_REV;IBAN;RAC_STAND;PD;REJT
6020833;33800;3016;02579731;76308116879,00;40260165;0;N.G.D., D.O.O.U LIKVIDACIJI;51000;RIJEKA;GNAMBOVA 2;70110;4110;8;373;28.3.2017 0:00:00;30;makol-consulting@inet.hr;1;MARINA BEGONJA - OSTOJIĆ;689-185;;LUKA PREBIL;5;1;18.4.2017 9:16:02;1.1.2017 0:00:00;28.2.2017 0:00:00;1;21;N;N;3;0;100;0;0;0;0;03451356;MAKOL - CONSULTING, D.O.O.;makol.consulting@gmail.com;0;2;E;1;;;D;; ;H;;
6021206;33800;2320;01861506;17637062639,00;40201532;0;INTERPROJEKT U LIKVIDACIJI D.O.O.;51000;RIJEKA;CIOTTINA 14;70120;6810;8;373;28.3.2017 0:00:00;30;inter-projekt@yahoo.co.uk;1;SILVIA ŠTIGLIĆ PETROVIĆ;051504878;;GEORGIJ TESLJA-TESLJENKO;5;1;25.4.2017 17:12:53;1.1.2017 0:00:00;23.2.2017 0:00:00;1;21;N;N;3;0;100;0;0;0;0;03479323;KTP D.O.O.;ktp@ktp.hr;12;2;E;1;;;D;; ;H;;
6022777;32700;2776;01335316;11085102484,00;80195265;0;RESTORAN - PETROKEMIJA, D.O.O.;44320;KUTINA;ALEJA VUKOVAR 4;55300;5610;3;220;30.3.2017 0:00:00;40;zlatko.grdic@petrokemija.hr;0;ZDRAVKO KOMBEREC;044/647-823;;ZLATKO GRDIĆ;5;0;18.4.2017 9:31:18;1.1.2017 0:00:00;2.1.2017 0:00:00;1;42;N;N;3;100;0;0;0;0;0;; ;zdravko.komberec@petrokemija.hr;12;1;E;2;;3674223;D;; ;H;;
6023574;34300;16;01503553;77934773507,00;50031995;0;EURO-MOBILE D.O.O. U LIKVIDACIJI;35000;SLAVONSKI BROD;A. M. RELJKOVIĆA 2A;74140;7022;12;396;30.3.2017 0:00:00;30;hknezevic@tuv-croatia.hr;1;;0958915340;;DAJANA KNEŽEVIĆ;5;1;30.3.2017 15:39:48;1.1.2017 0:00:00;26.1.2017 0:00:00;1;21;N;N;1;100;0;0;0;0;0;04311370; ;euroaccount@net.hr;12;1;E;1;;;D;; ;H;;
```

If I try to import this file using read.table:

```
zaglav <- read.table(file = 'E:/data/poslovni_subjekti/2018/ZAGLAV.txt', header = TRUE, 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ';', dec = ",",
                     colClasses = c("OIB"="character",  "NKD2002"="character", "NKD2007"='character',
```

It doesn't import all columns. It seems the problem is in 55'th column, which contain solo "," or solo space.

Comment: Are you sure about 55?  This reports that there are 54 fields on every line:`count.fields(textConnection(Lines), sep = ";")` where Lines is a character string containing the text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use fread from data.table package? Sometimes it circumvents such issues.

```
library(data.table)
zaglav <- fread(file = 'E:/data/poslovni_subjekti/2018/ZAGLAV.txt')
```

Comment: I did, but same result